# Where to find a Calendar control?

Tags: c#, calendar

I was trying to see if I could customize the [`MonthCalendar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) control to be more of an event calendar, where you could type in text in each of the day, or have an action happen when the day is clicked.

However, Month Calendar is very different than what I want. Will I have to create an entire new calendar for the event calendar, like a 6x7 grid where each cell represents a day? Or is there a simpler way?

This is what the MonthCalendar control looks like:

[image: Month Calendar]
<sub>(source: [dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/monthcalendar.png))</sub>

This is what I want:
[image: Event Calendar]

Comment: Creating your own custom control will give you greater control on the functionality. I'd prefer to develop my own control.

Comment: @Manish yes, let's reinvent the wheel. I'd say look for third-party components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the DevExpress components, they have the XtraScheduler which does exactly this and even much much more. Their Scheduler is available for all platforms, ASP.NET, SL, MVC, Windows Forms, WPF...

I am not aware of any free solution right now, at least not at that level, you can download their trial and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Devexpress `XtraScheduler` component is what you need. Check it on [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1971), search on [Devexpress support](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=XtraScheduler) and you can find a lot of videos on [Devexress TV](http://www.youtube.com/user/DeveloperExpress) about it.

[image]